# why not partial class to build the ViewModel in MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, xaml, mvvm

Why not use partial class to build the ViewModel?

Since the definition of viewmodel classes have some definition of the data classes of datamodel, why not try to reduce some work, extending or making partial classes of the datamodel, completing them with command and etc.

Comment: Are you saying define the Model and ViewModel in the same class?

Answer (score 5):

In some cases this may be useful, but generally the ViewModel (or PresentationModel) has a different set of concerns that would muddle the rest of the model.

For example, imagine that you have an object model that represents an order processing workflow (everybody's favorite example.) This same model might be underlying a WPF, a web site, and perhaps even other services.
Within the WPF application there will be WPF-specific concerns for presentation. Adding these concerns to primary model (even as partial classes) results in a violation of SRP. Ultimately, it would obscure the intent of model and make it difficult for consumers of the model to know which parts of it where essential and which were incidental.

Answer (score 0):

I agree but there are also extensions that seem to belong in a partial class as well.  For example, a calculated field (say an invoice total), useful on the client and perhaps the viewmodel exposes it for data binding to the UI, however it's really a property of the entity. It may not be represented in the model itself because it can be derrived from the entity's other properties, and IMO better represented by using a partial class to extend the domain entity.